# Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/core__init.class or clojure/core.clj on classpath

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, clojure, amazon-ses

I'm getting the below exception while trigerring the email service at remote server(**EC2 linux instance**). but it is working fine in my local. Although I have tried with the same war(from my local) on remote server but it failed again giving the same exception.

```
22-Mar-2021 13:10:47.510 SEVERE [TP-Source-6e5b00ec-14a3-4a73-896b-44e2428c0afa-3] org.springframework.aop.interceptor.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler.handleUncaughtException Unexpected exception occurred invoking async method: public void com.myproject.web.service.EmailService.sendMessageWithAttachment(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at clojure.core$clojure_version.<clinit>(core.clj:6788)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.languageVersion(VersionInfoUtils.java:281)
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.clojureVersion(VersionInfoUtils.java:204)
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.getAdditionalJvmLanguages(VersionInfoUtils.java:191)
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.userAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:161)
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.initializeUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:137)
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.getUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:100)
at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.<clinit>(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:44)
at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.<init>(InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.java:36)
at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.<init>(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:102)
at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.<init>(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:82)
at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.<init>(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:66)
at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.<clinit>(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:49)
at com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper.initializeProvider(EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper.java:64)
at com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper.<init>(EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper.java:53)
at com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.<init>(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:49)
at com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.<clinit>(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:43)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.java:46)
at com.myproject.web.service.EmailService.sendMessageWithAttachment(EmailService.java:85)
at com.myproject.web.service.EmailService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f3f8deb8.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/core__init.class or clojure/core.clj on classpath.
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:449)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
at clojure.lang.RT.doInit(RT.java:454)
at clojure.lang.RT.<clinit>(RT.java:330)
... 32 more
```

I'm using the **AWS SES and S3 jar** (version 1.11.795) to send email instead of aws-java-sdk jar.
I tried installing the clojure at the server but it is failing and giving the same error.

please suggest.

Comment: "but it is working fine in my local." what does that mean? How did you build the war and how do you run the service locally?

Comment: i'm using eclipse in local.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the build steps & output. It is usually easiest to use the "standalone" JAR file created by `lein uberjar` (eg `/home/alan/expr/demo/target/uberjar/demo-art-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar`).

Comment: It might be worth to check the versions of the JDK on your local environment and in your EC2 host.